# is there a way to send data from unity c# and python program?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

i have a unity project and i want to send the position of the object alongside some other data from it to a python project that will have a neural network then sending the output back to unity.

the data that i need to send from unity to python is the position of the object (x,y,z) and some bools maybe some strings, the output of the neural network will be (w,a,s,d), what i did is that i wrote the data to a text file and the python read the data from that file but this way will always produce an error because the python will need to read the file while c# is writing which will produce IO error, another way is using clipboard but this will be viable for small data but won't be good in my case.

**c# code**

```
void Update()
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter saveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Reading/Positions/PlanePos.txt", false);
        saveFile.Write(this.transform.position);
        saveFile.Close();
        System.IO.StreamWriter saveFile2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Reading/Positions/done.txt", false);
        if (this.transform.position.y> 2)
        {
            leftground = true;
        }
        if (leftground)
        {
            if (this.transform.position.y < 2)
            {
                saveFile2.Write("done");
                saveFile2.Flush();
                dones.text = "done";
            }
            else
            {
                saveFile2.Write("air");
                saveFile2.Flush();
                dones.text = "air";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            saveFile2.Write("ground");
            saveFile2.Flush();
            dones.text = "ground";
        }
        saveFile2.Close();
    }
```

**Python Code:**

```
    def read_data():
        # reading from file
        file = open("D:/Cs/Grad/Tests/airplane test/Reading/Positions/PlanePos.txt", "r")
        planepos = file.readline()
        file.close()
        file = open("D:/Cs/Grad/Tests/airplane test/Reading/Positions/AirportPosition.txt", "r")
        airportpos = file.readline()
        file.close()
        # ==================================================================
        # spliting and getting numbers
        #plane_X, plane_Y, plane_Z = map(float, planepos.strip('() \n').split(','))
        #airport_X, airport_Y, airport_Z = map(float, airportpos.strip('() \n').split(','))
        planepos=planepos.strip('() \n').split(',')
        airportpos=airportpos.strip('() \n').split(',')
        return planepos[0], planepos[1], planepos[2], airportpos[0], airportpos[1], airportpos[2]
```

**i except a way to send data from unity to python and vice versa like a server or anything that can do this.**

Comment: Why you don't want to use server?

Comment: You can write an API server or socket server with Python and then connect to that server from Unity using c# and transfer data.

Comment: @Raguel i don't want to use server because i don't know how exactly i can do it but if you tell me how i will try to do it.

Comment: @AminSojoudi could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @yousiffayed there are a lot of tutorials on the net, check this for creating simple Rest API's with python: https://linuxhint.com/rest_api_python/, then you can use Unity web request to post or get data from the server https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html

Comment: It is not really hard to create, so give it a try. You can create it with python's socket, but what @AminSojoudi send is the best way to create something like that, plus you will learn many new things. If you are interested in creating with sockets, then might recommend you sentdex on YouTube about sockets.

Comment: @Raguel  and AminSojoudi thank you both for your help